# Does calling actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result block anything in a custom model binder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using WebAPI 2. I have a custom model binder that creates the model from the json in the request's body.

But I can see (or google) no way to access the request body synchronously. So what I've seen people doing is usually something like:

```
actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

with Result forcing the call to be synchronous from the perspective of the caller. It does look like [aspnetcore does support async model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but I'm using regular WebAPI 2 on the .NET Framework and my only option is:

```
public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
```

Why is it async in the first place? I'm no expert on the OSI model but shouldn't I have the entire request by the time it gets to the model binder?

Comment: My guess is that there must be some reason for `ReadAsStringAsync` to only be async. The only reason for that which I can imagine is that we haven't received the entire request yet.